# The [which] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) tag is rather vaguely described as:

> The selection of a set of data from another set.

This tag is very ambiguous, and could refer to several different technologies with equal validity. The vast majority of questions are about R, but there are also Python, JavaScript, and Unix questions thrown in for good measure. My first thought was that we could edit those out, but when I looked closer I realized that they're no less valid of a use than the R questions are.

As of 2020-09-17 06:30 UTC, there are 356 questions with the tag.  Only one of the top askers has asked more than one question with the tag.  A number of the top answerers have answered multiple questions with the tag (one has answered 28, another 14, and 9 others of the top 30 have answered more than one question).

Can we burninate this?

[Link](https://youtu.be/X2xlQaimsGg) for those who don't know what the original title (before mandatory editing due to this being featured) was referring to.

Comment: It turned me into a newt!

Comment: But is it made of wood?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- The [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions are using it for the [which function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which), which is too granular to warrant a tag. Simply remove it
- For UNIX/Linux related questions, the best tag to add/replace it with is [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)
- **Remember that most shell related questions are on-topic!**

## Progress:

The [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=which),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhich%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhich%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhich%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhich%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

[Rodgort burnination tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I have edited [tag:which] to include the "DO NOT USE" guidance from the burnination process template.

Comment: This is my first ever burnination, so maybe this is a dumb question, but the which tag has some questions closed as duplicates. Since at the end all closed questions will be deleted by the system, should I remove the tag from the duplicates so as to prevent value being lost?

Comment: [tag:which] is not part of [tag:bash] but more of [tag:shell]. It is not part of the bash language, but is a command that can be used in any shell (bash,ksh,sh,zsh,fish)

Comment: The burnination is complete: Only 8 closed questions remain.

Answer (score 57):

To answer [the burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/325771):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   I'd say sort-of for the first one (see answer on point 3), and a definite no on the second point, given the plethora of associated `which` functions in various languages.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   This depends on which `which` we consider. UNIX' `which` would be off-topic and should go to either [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), but questions about a valid function in R or Python might be on-topic here.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**
   Sort-of again. On the one hand, yes, since it's the name of a function that's used in the question, on the other hand, if we need a tag for every function used in a question we'd need a (much) higher tag limit than 5.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   As established under 1. and the question itself: no. Various languages and operating systems have various uses for it.

Considering the above I am in favour of burninating the tag.

Comment: I must mention that to be burned, the tag has to fall under all 4 burnination criteria, and this one clearly does not. That said, I think a better approach would be to refine it to something useful (like [tag:if-statement]), maybe rename it as well (as it is hard as hell to find anything related as it is a part of natural language)

Comment: @OlegValter how isn't it a clear "no" on each of the criteria? It's either a sole no, or a "depends on the `which`, and then again probably no". Can you clarify why you think it's "clearly" not a no on each of the criteria?

Comment: @Adriaan - maybe I misunderstood you, but the 1 & 2 & 3 reads as only partially in favour of burning, and as far as I recall, burning requires clear fail on all criteria ( not judging the merit of such a restriction ). I am not defending the tag, though - as it stands now, I think it is, well, not very useful, and your points are valid, just mention that we can go a less destructive route of bringing it into shape

Comment: @OlegValter 1,2,3 are in favour of burnination. It's a for-sure burn for UNIX's `which`, and unless you want to end up with tags for `r-which`, `python-which`, `java-which`, `php-which` etc ad nauseam, those can be burninated as well as per my answer. Could you please detail what you mean with a "less-destructive route"? I see only very few ways of dealing with this, which mainly involves creating all the mentioned language-specific tags.

Comment: @Adriaan - hm, what about making it a [tag:which-function] (and giving it a wiki)? Seems like on-topic questions are about them. Plus it is [searchable](https://www.google.com/search?q=which-function). We can retag/close the rest of the q's that are off-topic/incorrectly tagged then (if there still are). Certainly not in favour of combining with language tags, I agree that those should be burned on the spot. Re:criteria - I think, if the content is on-topic at least in part (#2), we shall strive to find a way to bring it in shape ( that said, it isn't my intention to get adversarial on that )

Comment: @OlegValter having the tag called which or which-function is moot to me. Might as well update the tag-wiki of [tag:which] in the first place. The entire problem with that name though is as mentioned in the question, and point 1 and 3 of my answer here: it'd be ambiguous due to the plethora of different languages with a `which` functionality, all of which are implemented differently and do different things. So no, having a *single* tag for all those functions lumped together isn't a good thing IMO.

Comment: Yes, questions about certain `which` functions might be on-topic, but we don't need a tag about every single function in `java` either. So the concept of `which` can be on-topic, but I haven't yet seen compelling arguments as to why a "random" function in a "random" language should have its own tag.

Comment: @Adriaan - I know R has `which` function, but I don't know of any in Java (`which [insert name here]` is asked only in context of using shell) and PHP ( if you referred to [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which+java), they ask for alternatives ). Maybe I am lacking some domain knowledge, but it seems like the alternative is R/UNIX, we can simply disambiguate. It has reasonable amount of watchers (50), [75%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which+r) of q's are about R. Also, maybe we should ask [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) to weigh in?

Comment: @OlegValter at the very least [MATLAB has a `which`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) as well, and probably more languages do. So I'm still no fan of disambiguation, as you'd need `r-which`, `php-which` and `matlab-which` at the very least, presumably more languages need to be added at some point. Besides, at least for the MATLAB one, there's in my opinion no need for having the tag. That'd be like creating `matlab-for` or something.

Comment: @Adriaan - I would say MATLAB's which is much closer to how shell `which` command works (but I'll take your word for it). I see only 2 interpretations of `which`: either "find a file/folder" or "find an index" (as in R [which](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which)). If we find a way to split those, I don't think there will ever be a need for language-specific tags (the on-topic is specific to R and doesn't do any active harm). Maybe the best would be to give it to R? Judging from amount of q's issues with the func are prominent enough to warrant a niche tag.

Comment: Why hasn't the tag been burninated yet?

Comment: @TechExpertWizard not everything happens instantly. As you can see, just 4 hours before you left your comment, a moderator edited the question into phase 2.

Comment: @TechExpertWizard We need to do this properly and according to custom and tradition. `which`es are to be bunrninated at the steak, and as anyone whose operates a grill can tell you, don't rush a steak. The seasoning and charring has to be juuuuust right.

Comment: Overall I think that other flow-control structures like [tag:if-statement], [tag:for-loop], [tag:foreach] or keywords in general should be removed or better synonymized with something like [tag:control-constructs]. Combined with a proper language tag would disambiguate the complete thing. I have the feeling that most of the tags are just created to get the badges related to it. There is too much micro-tag-management.

Comment: @kvantour on the more general of those (`if`, `for` etc) I agree, they usually do not add much in terms of relevancy to a question. Getting badges in those is rather trivial (and problematic if you can dupehammer e.g. C++ questions when you've only answered in Python). There are, however, specific ones like [tag:parfor] which carry a whole set of non-obvious rules and syntaxes, which IMO do deserve their own tag.

Comment: @Adriaan, using the tags `[tag:matlab], [tag:parallel], [tag:control-construct]` would make this clear. Especially since the question would mention [tag:parfor] specifically. But this is up for debate obviously and not currently the discussion. I was more referring to the more classic _ideologies_ here. `parfor` could be an exception as all languages have such construct.